# CheckBox two way binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I want to make two way binding for checkboxes inside ListView. This is my Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In ViewModel class I have observable collection of products:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Product> _productList;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductList
    {
        get
        {
            return _productList;
        }
        set
        {
            _productList = value;
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ProductList = new ObservableCollection<Product>
                          {
                              new Product {IsSelected = false, Name = "Not selected"},
                              new Product {IsSelected = true, Name = "Selected"},
                              new Product {IsSelected = true, Name = "Selected"}
                          };
    }
}
```

And finally I have Grid with ListView that binding my ProductList:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="40">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Product Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

When I debug this app it never arrive to setter's line when I check/uncheck checkboxes. 
Any ideas what is wrong in this code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/504936/440030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bound the CheckBox to the IsSelected property. This property is implemented as an [auto implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). You will never break at the setter or getter in debugger. I can't see any issue in your code, it should work like you've coded it.

Answer (score 2):

For two way binding to work you should first of all implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` event in your view Model and product class to make sure when there is some change in property  view is notified instantly

Also make sure you are setting `DataContext` of view correctly

```
view.DataContext = yourViewModel;
```

and as Fischermaen mentioned you won't be able to debug this kind of property you should do something like this if you want to debug

```
 public class Product
    {
        private bool isSelected;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set { isSelected = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement on binded type `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and in case when `IsSelected` propertyis *set* have to notify about it.

Docs and sample from msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx